# Python Trimming a few column names but not all in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of many columns. Now I am trimming a few columns to reduce the text length.

Code:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[10,25],'Column2':[10,25],'Fix_col':[10,25]})

## Rename `Column1` to `C1` and for `C2` as well
req_cols = ['Column1','Column2']

xdf[req_cols].columns = [x[0]+y for name in xdf[req_cols].str.findall(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)' for x,y in name]
```

Present solution:

```
print([x[0]+y for name in xdf[req_cols].str.findall(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)' for x,y in name])
['C1','C2']
print(xdf[req_cols].columns)
['Column1','Column2']
```

Column names did not change. Don't know why?

Expected Answer:

```
xdf.columns = ['C1','C2','Fix_col']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

xdf = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[10,25],'Column2':[10,25],'Fix_col':[10,25]})
req_cols = ['Column1','Column2']

xdf.rename(columns=lambda x : x if x not in req_cols else re.sub(r'^(\D?)\D*(\d*)', r'\1\2', x), inplace=True)
```

Output of `xdf.columns`:

```
Index(['C1', 'C2', 'Fix_col'], dtype='object')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u0YDoZ/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\D?)` - Group 1 (`\1`): an optional non-digit char
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digit chars
- `(\d*)` - Group 2 (`\2`): zero or more digits.

Comment: Your solution nailed it. Thanks for explaining each character and what it is doing. Being a beginner helps me. Also, why is the difference between `r'^(\D?)\D*(\d*)'` and `r'\1\2'`. Also, if I want to change the column name from `Row.1.2` to `1.2`, what should be the expression here?

Comment: @Mainland `^(\D?)\D*(\d*)` is a regex pattern and ``\1\2`` is a replacement pattern. To keep everything after the first digit use `r'^\D*(\d.*)'` as regex and replace with `r'\1'`.

Comment: I have a list `cols = ['2.19', '2.20', '9.1', '9.2', '9.3']`.  I want to extract the strings starting with `9.`. I am doing regex `[cols.findall(r`([9\.]+)`)]`. But this matches all the strings with `.` as well. How can I match exact strings only?